# Boolean Object and boolean variable issue in JAVA

Tags: java

I declare a Boolean variable. For example `Boolean dataVal=null;`
Now if I execute the following code segment:

```
if(dataVal)
    System.out.println("\n\NULL value in dataVal: "+dataVal);
else
    System.out.println("\n\nvalue in dataVal: "+dataVal);
```

I get `NullPointerException`. Well, I know its obvious, but I need to know the reason behind this.

Comment: whats Reason ? Its null so nullpointerException that reason

Comment: boolean=null; ? Thats incorrect Java grammar. Right?

Comment: @Russell - `Boolean` is an object, not a primitive, ergo null makes sense.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When you evaluate the boolean value of a `Boolean` object Java unbox the value (autoboxing feature, since 1.5). So the real code is: `dataVal.booleanValue()`. Then it throws `NullPointerException`. With any boxed value, unboxing a null object throws this exception.

Before 1.5 you had to unbox the value by hand: `if (dataVal.booleanValue())` so it was more evident (more verbose too :)

Answer (score 16):

Because `dataVal` is being casted to `boolean` using `Boolean.booleanValue()` which gets translated to `null.booleanValue()` which leads you to a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 5):

You can have a look at the specification for unboxing issues, your situation is described [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html) section **5.1.8 Unboxing Conversion** : *If r is null, unboxing conversion throws a NullPointerException*

That means your if ( /* Boolean object */ ) will never be unboxed into a boolean primitive type and therefore throw a NPE because you are doing an invalid `if(null)`.

By the way, unboxing will work if you had:

```
final Boolean booleanTest = new Boolean (true);
if (booleanTest) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Boolean (class) != boolean (primitive type).

Java tries to get the primitive value calling dataVal.booleanValue(). Because dataVal is null, you get a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

use BooleanUtils.tobolean(?), it returns false if the passed param is null

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all - why exactly the NPE occurs. You answered the question how to prevent it, but the OP didn't ask this.

Answer (score 0):

`if(null)` is not a valid expression, simple as that.

Under the hoods, the VM is using auto-boxing... so you get a `NullPointerException.`

Answer (score 0):

When you try to evaluate Boolean object  value jvm internally call booleanValue() on that object as you assign null to that object it will throw NullPointerException