# Presence of request param should evaluate to true

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc

Say I have an endpoint that accepts requests as follows:

`GET https://my.website.com/products?expired`

OR

`GET https://my.website.com/products`

The method I would expect to work:

```
@GetMapping
public List<Product> products(@RequestParam(value = "expired", required=false) boolean expired) {
   //Implementation details
}
```

This however, will return a Bad Request `400` response.

I know I would get this to work by sending the `expired` requestParam as `expired=true`, but I'd like for this to work similar to [HTML boolean attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139786/what-does-it-mean-in-html-5-when-an-attribute-is-a-boolean-attribute) where the mere presence of a request param represents `true` and its absence represents `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you'll have to implement two methods, one with and one without the param, the second with it required (and probably `Boolean` non-primitive, as the other answer suggests).

(Then just call a common method from both.)

Answer (score 4):

Use `Boolean` instead of `boolean` - the problem you have is that you are trying to unbox `null` value to the primitive `boolean` which operation causes `NullpointerException` and further Bad Request `400` response

```
public List<Product> products(@RequestParam(value = "expired", required=false) Boolean expired)
```

[Here you can read something more about unboxing Boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479806/boolean-object-and-boolean-variable-issue-in-java)

Comment: Sending a `GET` request to `https://my.website.com/products?expired` will evaluate the value of the `click` variable to `null`

Comment: @Robin-Hoodie That;'s right. So you need to treat `null` the same was `false` to achieve what you want.

Comment: That doesn't satisfy my question though, the presence of the `expired` request param should be enough to have it evaluate to `true`

Comment: Ok I see - I believe that what you're trying to achieve is not possible in an easy way and even if you would do this it would be misleading. You should create specific endpoint like `website.com/products/expired` for your purpose or just keep on setting specific `true/false` value